# How can I trace back "EPROTONOSUPPORT: protocol not supported :::3000" in node.js?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I am more than clueless at the moment. I am trying to start a keystonejs-6 app in production mode and the the app throws this error:

```
Starting Keystone
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EPROTONOSUPPORT: protocol not supported :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1559:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EPROTONOSUPPORT',
  errno: -43,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

I have no way to trace back, at which point of the keystonejs application code the error originated. As it seems, keystonejs provides practically no logging on the application code itself.

Is there a way to find out, what kind of protocol is meant by this error message?

Comment: Woah, that's a weird one. So when Node is attempting to open a TCP socket on port 3000 it's getting an error back (from the OS?) saying the protocol is invalid. Never seen anything like that but it's well below the level Keystone itself operates on. What OS and Node version are you using? What happens if you start a minimal server server like this? https://tannerdolby.com/writing/build-a-minimal-http-server-with-node

Comment: @Molomby Thanks for your reply. It was, in fact, a bug happening on empty hostname in some OSs.

It's described here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/8131#issue-1465219895

It's been fixed since version 4.0.0 of @keystone/core .

Comment: Ah ok, I stand corrected. So using "::" (the previous KS default) produced an EPROTONOSUPPORT error, probably when the OS didn't support IPv6. Omitting the host value (the new KS default) causes nodejs to use either IPv4, IPv6 or both depending on what the OS supports, avoiding the error.